# Splitting a multi-dimensional array

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a set of dynamically created arrays which are stored as one array.

The first entry in each nested array will always be the name of the taxonomy, with the proceeding items being categories associated with that taxonomy.

I would like to use this data to create a URL which in turn will run a query on another page, like this;

```
http://example.com/?stoma=colostomy&problem=leaks,odour
```

How would I split each nested array dynamically to create this structure?

Here is how the array is created: https://codepen.io/chops07876/pen/xXWVVy

**UPDATE:**

I have figured out how to split the arrays accordingly, is this the most efficient way of do so though?

```
query = '';

$(result).each(function(i){
    if(result[i].length >= 2) {
        taxonomy = result[i][0];
        categories = result[i].slice(1);
        query += taxonomy+'='+categories+'&';
    }
});

console.log(query.slice(0,-1));
```

Comment: Your *"like so"* example doesn't make any sense

Comment: Sorry, removed that example. I think it's clear enough without anyhow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your data, i.e., what the nested array looks like. A link to an external site with code that creates the array isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unless dealing with millions, you shouldn't worry about performance.

Here's one way of doing it, as a combination of `filter`, `map` and `join`.

```js
var arrays = [[], ["stoma", "colostomy"], ["problem", "leaks", "odour"]];

function stringify( arrays ){
  
  // Remove all elements of length < 2.
  var filtered = arrays.filter(function(array){
    return array.length > 1;
  });

  // Convert every array into a string (tax=cat1,cat2...)
  var strings = filtered.map(function(array){
    var taxonomy = array[0];
    var categories = array.slice(1);
    return taxonomy + "=" + categories.join(",")
  });
  
  // Join all previous strings with `&` and add a `?` on beginning.
  return "?" + strings.join("&");
  
}

console.log( stringify(arrays) )
```

Here's the same thing as an ES6 one-liner

```
(arrays) => "?" + arrays.filter(({length}) => length > 1).map(([tax, ...cats]) => `${tax}=${cats.join(",")}`).join("&")
```